# Show pickup locations on Google Maps and SERP

Tags: ranking, local-seo, google-maps, google-my-business

Having trouble getting a clear answer to this but wondering how do places like Zipcar get their locations on google maps without having a physical location there? Is this all done organically by crawling addresses on their website or is there a way to add these places directly on either Google Maps or Google My Business?

This is based on a company offers car rental and has a central office. They then have pickup/drop off locations in 3 cities. I can't add these to Google My Business as extra locations since they can't be verified and creating labels on Google Maps seems to only work for personal maps only and not searchable.

The website we are looking to rank is built with Duda and they do have a Google Maps widget with the addresses on a couple pages. These are perhaps being crawled and built automatically?

*I am posting for my own personal knowledge but also about a specific use case another SEO agency I am partnering with is facing so out of respect for their client relationship I will not be sharing the business name or url.

[image]

Comment: Isn't a place where you can pick up a car a physical location?   It isn't a store front, but it sounds like a physical location to me.

Comment: Normally yes, however with Zipcar as an example these are parking spots with a zipcar sign, no building.

Comment: Zipcar likely is getting special treatment due to a partnership or the degree to which the service has become mainstream.

Comment: That is the consensus I've gotten so far that Tesla and Zipcar probably have an agreement with Google.